# Is there a way to use a Javascript variable in CSS to customize colour, or an alternative way to achieve this?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, random

I'm trying to make it so that when you over over certain elements on a webpage, they change to random colour of a predefined pallette.

I've written a basic scrip in JS that picks from an existing colour pallette.

```
const pal = ["93FFF2","F8A5FF","FFBA41","71FF5B","9D6CFF"]
const txtCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * pal.length);
console.log(txtCol, pal[txtCol]);
```

Then, ideally, I could use the "txtCol" value in my CSS, like so...

```
nav a:hover {
    color: (txtCol);
}
```

Obviously, that doesn't work. Is there any way I can achieve what I want this to do?
Many thanks :)

Comment: Yes there are css variables that can be changed using js

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score 3):

You can do a combination of css variables and setting variables with javascript for every `mouseenter` event (when the hover starts):

```css
nav a:hover {
  color: var(--hover-color);
}
```

```js
const pal = ["93FFF2","F8A5FF","FFBA41","71FF5B","9D6CFF"]
// every time the user starts hovering that element
document.querySelector('nav a').addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
  // pick the random color
  const txtCol = pal[Math.floor(Math.random() * pal.length)];
  // set the css variable
  event.target.style.setProperty('--hover-color', '#' + txtCol)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I apologise for my lack of understanding, but I'm getting an error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')` when using that code, do you know what could be causing this? Thank you!

Comment: @Max that at the time when you run this code, there is no `<a>` inside of a `<nav>` on the page.

Comment: @Thomas Perfect! thanks so much both of you